# How do I show a thumbnail of the uploaded image instantly using Paperclip?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So in my app, users can upload an image to their blog. Now right when they choose the file I'd like to instantly show a thumbnail of the uploaded image so they know which image they've selected before pressing "Submit" on the form.

How might I do this?

here's my current code:

```
  <hr>
  <h4>Name your blog<br />
  & upload an image for it</h4><br />


  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "blog-name", placeholder: "Name it here" %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  ----> I'd like to show the image here, instantly <----
  <%= f.submit "Next", class: "next-button" %>
  <br><br>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paperclip cannot show image preview instantly. [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is a plugin for Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord that lets files work as simply as any other attributes do. There are no extra database tables, only one library to install for image processing, and the ease of being able to refer to your files as easily as you refer to your other attributes.

You can achieve instant image preview using javascript/jQuery. Below is the code for showing image preview.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/4669/).

Html:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function readURL(input) {

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: this is great! although can i do this and still save the image to server? if we can join the 2 we'd be all set

Comment: This code just shows the selected image from file field. It will not affect your form fields & image submission to server. Submit your form as usually and it will work.

Comment: Ah last question, how can I ONLY show the thumbnail once the image is added? Right now it's showing a broken image icon until I upload the image?

Comment: In fact, this is only happening on Chrome, on FireFox the ALT seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: but i found the trick for it,, here is solution http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/4669/   when the source of image tag is empty, it shows broken image icon.. So basically assign a default image to it.. refer HTML in jsFiddle.